# AoC Day 8 2022 - Pola-rs Dataframes

Tags: rust

Description of the problem and the input data is here https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/8. The algorithm is essentially:

- Find the cumulative max value in a given direction and shift by 1
- Find the values that exceed the cumulative max in a given direction as a boolean mask
- Translate the dataframe for the other 3 directions and repeat the first two steps
- Bitor the 4 resultant boolean masks and sum the true values

It's my first time using Pola-rs and the lack of operations defined on the dataframe struct and need to iterate over series made this end up quite verbose compared to the equivalent Pandas so I'm curious to see if I have any obviously redundant code and if there are more idiomatic/efficient ways to use Pola-rs expression mechanism.

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let file_contents = fs::read_to_string("data/input.txt").expect("Valid file");
    println!("Result for part 1 is {}", result_1(&file_contents).unwrap());
}

fn result_1(input: &str) -> Result<i32> {
    let lines: Vec<&str> = input.trim().split("\n").collect();
    let tree_map = tree_map(lines);
    let cols: Vec<&str> = tree_map.get_column_names().into_iter().rev().collect();

    let cummax_from_top = tree_map.cummax_height_from_n()?;
    let cummax_from_left = tree_map.transpose()?.cummax_height_from_n()?;
    let cummax_from_bottom = tree_map.reverse().cummax_height_from_n()?;
    let cummax_from_right = tree_map.transpose()?.reverse().cummax_height_from_n()?;

    let visible_from_top = trees_visible(&tree_map, cummax_from_top)?;
    let visible_from_left = trees_visible(&tree_map.transpose()?, cummax_from_left)?.transpose()?;
    let visible_from_bottom = trees_visible(&tree_map.reverse(), cummax_from_bottom)?.reverse();
    let visible_from_right = trees_visible(&tree_map.transpose()?.reverse(), cummax_from_right)?
        .transpose()?
        .select(&cols)?;

    let visible_mask = visible_from_top
        .bitor(visible_from_left)?
        .bitor(visible_from_bottom.bitor(visible_from_right)?)?;

    let result = visible_mask
        .sum()
        .hsum(NullStrategy::Ignore)?
        .unwrap()
        .sum::<i32>()
        .unwrap();

    Ok(result)
}

fn tree_map(lines: Vec<&str>) -> DataFrame {
    let mut rows: Vec<Series> = Vec::new();
    for (idx, line) in lines.iter().enumerate() {
        let digits: Series = line
            .to_string()
            .chars()
            .map(|d| d.to_digit(10).unwrap() as i32)
            .collect();
        rows.push(Series::new(&idx.to_string(), digits));
    }
    DataFrame::new(rows).unwrap().transpose().unwrap()
}

fn trees_visible(tree_map: &DataFrame, cummax: DataFrame) -> Result<DataFrame> {
    let mask = tree_map
        .get_column_names()
        .iter()
        .map(|name| {
            when(col(name).gt(col(&format!("{name}_right"))))
                .then(col(name))
                .otherwise(lit(NULL))
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Expr>>();

    Ok(tree_map
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .with_context(&[cummax.lazy().select(&[all().suffix("_right")])])
        .select(&mask)
        .collect()?
        .lazy()
        .select([all().is_not_null()])
        .collect()?)
}

trait ElementWise {
    fn bitor(&self, df: DataFrame) -> Result<DataFrame>;
    fn cummax_height_from_n(&self) -> Result<DataFrame>;
}

impl ElementWise for DataFrame {
    fn bitor(&self, df_2: DataFrame) -> Result<DataFrame> {
        Ok(DataFrame::new(
            self.iter()
                .zip(df_2.iter())
                .map(|(series1, series2)| series1.bitor(series2).unwrap())
                .collect(),
        )?)
    }

    fn cummax_height_from_n(&self) -> Result<DataFrame> {
        Ok(self
            .clone()
            .lazy()
            .select([all().cummax(false).shift(1).fill_null(-1)])
            .collect()?)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_part_1() {
        let file_contents = fs::read_to_string("data/demo_input.txt")
            .expect("Should have been able to read the file");
        let res = result_1(&file_contents).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(res, 21);
    }
}
```